# Restore/Imaging On Different Physical Machines

Tags: windows-7, backup, mirroring, disk-image

I've used a couple of disk-imaging tools in the past; but they always required the hardware on the machine be identical to the one that created the image.  Is this still the case?

I have a work-related PC that requires a fair amount of specialized applications to be installed and configured.  I'm getting a new PC and wondering if I could create an 'image' of the old one and install it on the new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use Symantec Backup Exec System Recovery for this.  We also have a great deal of specialized software that takes a lot of time to install.  Save a great deal of time and really handy if the system fails.  Just took an image from an approximately one year old laptop and restored to a four year old model.  A few driver fixes and we were ready to go.
There is an eval on their site [Symantec BESR](http://www.symantec.com/business/products/family.jsp?familyid=backupexec)