# Can Windows 7/8 System Image Recovery be used to clone a PC to different hardware?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, clone, disk-image, ghost-image

Using the System Image Recovery option in Windows 7 & 8 (as detailed [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/restore-windows-8-with-system-image-recovery/) for Win8, and [here](http://www.cnet.com/uk/how-to/how-to-find-the-system-image-tool-in-windows-8-1/) for Win8.1) is it possible to create a system image on one machine, and restore it to another machine, with different hardware?

Of course, the target machine will need to already have Windows installed (or use a system recovery disc) and be of the same CPU architecture as the source.

I know in the past Microsoft added a limitation to Windows of *x* number of changes to hardware permitted before it would cease functioning.

I've searched and can't find this. These questions are related, but don't answer my question:

- [Create system image and install it on different machines](https://superuser.com/questions/692384/create-system-image-and-install-it-on-different-machines)
- [Create a Windows Image for Deployment](https://superuser.com/questions/46027/create-a-windows-image-for-deployment)
- [Restore/Imaging On Different Physical Machines](https://superuser.com/questions/199100/restore-imaging-on-different-physical-machines)

Comment: The system image in question isn't an image to restore your system, its to restore windows, so it can boot.  So if Windows is already installed, then the recovery image isn't required, and yes a Windows 8.1 recovery image can work on **ANY** Windows 8.1 machine.

Comment: @Ramhound You're mistaken. It's a full system image.

Comment: I blame the horrible article in question.  The screenshot they used paint a different picture.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely not. If you're looking to build an image that will on multiple makes and models, you really want to look into building a reference image in a VM with MDT 2013 and then pushing an image to the make and model.

The issue you'll have is less to do with windows itself, but the drivers. Something as simple as a network card driver from config A could cause BSODs or other problems when loaded onto config B.

While you may have some luck loading the image to a VM and regeneralizing it, that method is likely doomed to fail. The problem is the image captured from hareware config A will have drivers that will cause nothing but problems in config B. You're really, really better off just building a reference image.

SEE: http://mdtguy.wordpress.com/build-a-windows-8-image/

Comment: I thought the System Image feature might give me a quick-and-dirty way for me to clone 1 PC to an additional 2. It was only as a one-off... When the machines arrive next week, I'll try it and give a more definitive answer than "most likely not".

Comment: Negative, That feature is really for "backups and restore" not for cloning devices. Again, you're welcome to try, but I'd advise against it. Even an image built on a Dell 9010 for instance wont load on a Dell 9020 over a chipset driver believe it or not. It just never ends well, It's why Desktop Engineers build reference images in VMs.